# Changing or removing a function within a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Perfect woocommerce brands only allows certain tags to be used and removes the rest via the function

```
if( isset( $_POST['pwb_brand_description_field'] ) ){
   $desc = strip_tags(
     wp_unslash( $_POST['pwb_brand_description_field'] ),
     '<p><span><a><ul><ol><li><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><pre><strong><em><blockquote><del><ins><img><code><hr>'
  );
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, [ 'description' => $desc ],     [ 'term_id' => $term_id ]  );
```

I am looking for a way to overide this so that I can include all tags, in particular `<div>`

I was hoping there might be something that I could add to functions.php which would help me achieve this?

Comment: @cale_b it is a plugin - https://github.com/titodevera/perfect-woocommerce-brands/blob/master/classes/admin/class-brands-custom-fields.php - link to the github sheet. the part I am querying is on lines 163-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the plugin author did not add any filters / hooks for this particular function, you have to do a fairly clunky work-around.

Thankfully, this function is called via a couple of actions

```
add_action( 'edit_pwb-brand', array( $this, 'add_brands_metafields_save' ) );
add_action( 'create_pwb-brand', array( $this, 'add_brands_metafields_save' ) );
```

That means that we *may* be able to add our own actions that run *after* those two, and *may* be able to do what you want.

**Note that this is sub-optimal but cannot be avoided**. This function is essentially running twice (the original in the plugin, plus yours), which is not good for performance - however, since this is only happening when an admin saves a brand, it shouldn't be too bad for performance.

First, add your own action(s) with a higher priority, then copy the original function with the desired modifications.

It's often recommended that you do this in your theme's functions.php file, but that's not ideal - what if you want to change themes, or update themes, but keep this functionality? Instead, **I strongly recommended** you build your own small, light-weight plugin. The complete code for such a plugin is below.  (Simply add this code to a PHP file, and place it in your plugins directory).

```
<?php
/**
 *  Plugin Name: Override Perfect WooCommerce Brands Meta
 *  Description: Custom override to permit div tags in brand meta description
 *  Version: 1.0.0
 *  Author: SupGen
 */

// Note the higher priority levels - to ensure these run AFTER the main plugin is done
add_action( 'edit_pwb-brand', 'override_add_brands_metafields_save', 9999 );
add_action( 'create_pwb-brand', 'override_add_brands_metafields_save', 9999 );

function override_add_brands_metafields_save( $term_id ) {
    // NOTE: hard-coding the file name here in order to verify the nonce.  MAY need to be changed
    $filename = 'class-brands-custom-fields.php';
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'pwb_nonce' ] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'pwb_nonce' ], $filename ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // removed bits you didn't care about, keeping only the relevant part

    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'pwb_brand_description_field' ] ) ) {
        // added div tag to allowed tags list
        $desc = strip_tags(
            wp_unslash( $_POST[ 'pwb_brand_description_field' ] ),
            '<div><p><span><a><ul><ol><li><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><pre><strong><em><blockquote><del><ins><img><code><hr>' 
        );

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, [ 'description' => $desc ], [ 'term_id' => $term_id ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, Thats excellent. I will need to try when back in the house, I have had to nip out. Just to check. once saving that snippet above as a plugin, would I then deactivate perfect woocommerce brands and  activate this? or will that snippet work through PWB?

Comment: You would add this plugin, and activate it.  You would have to keep PWB intact / in place to keep the PWB functionality.  The small plugin above is simply a small override to the one requested function in PWB.

Comment: your solution was an absolute gem. Thank you very much. I tried to up vote the post but I dont have a reputation of 15 :-(. But seriously, Thanks a lot for that!